# Does Intercom works with AngularJS and Ionic apps?

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, intercom

I was wondering if I could integrate my Intercom messaging to my hybrid app. I was searching around the web, but didn't find something to answer my question, therefor I'm writing this.

So, does anyone know if it's possible? If so, how did you guys do it?

Cheers!

Comment: please dont use the angular tag in angularjs related questions

Comment: So I should not use tags that are related to questions? @Jota.Toledo

Comment: the angularjs tag is for angularjs related questions, read the description of the angular tag

Comment: Please refer @MartinNordström https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/intercom/ and
https://developers.intercom.com/v2.0/docs/cordova-phonegap-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can integrate Intercom messaging in your ionic app using plugin cordova intercom plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-intercom
```

In you config file add:

```
<preference name="intercom-app-id" value="your-app-id" />
<preference name="intercom-ios-api-key" value="ios_sdk-....." />
<preference name="intercom-android-api-key" value="android_sdk-..." />
```

In your index file

```
<script>intercom.displayMessenger();</script>
```

In your controller after login:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      intercom.registerIdentifiedUser({userId: response.id});
      intercom.updateUser({ email: response.email, name: response.name });

     }, false);
```